# Coloring cell background on firemonkey stringgrid according to value from data

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

It may be basic but I'm have a **** of a time finding sample code to change a row color of a stringgrid based on a value from a database in Firemonkey. I have data coming from a MDB no problems but need the row to be certain colors for ie '1' = red '2' = green etc. I know I have to access the Style elements somehow 'OnApplyStyleLookup'? but at what stage. I have seen questions on changing text style and colour etc but I am digging a hole for myself trying to get to the 'background' element and applying. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers
Richard ...(newbie to Firemonkey)

Comment: To set the colour you'd need to override the SetData method of the cell, but the cell class is hard coded in a StringGrid. You'll need to use an ordinary grid with a custom cell class to do that. Take a look at my article at http://monkeystyler.com/blog/entry/firemonkey-grid-basics-custom-cells-and-columns for how to do that.

Comment: Thank muchly Mike. Your article looks well documented. I work full time ( not programming ) so I know what I will be doing this weekend.

Answer (score 5):

```
{OnDrawColumnCell event}

procedure OnDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Canvas: TCanvas; const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF;
  const Row: Integer; const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
var
  RowColor : TBrush;
begin

  RowColor := Tbrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid,TAlphaColors.Alpha);

{you can check for values and then set the color you want}
  if Value.ToString = 'red' then
     RowColor.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;

  Canvas.FillRect(Bounds, 0, 0, [], 1, RowColor);

  { perform default drawing }
  TGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Canvas, Column, Bounds, Row,
    Value, State);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code with Delphi Berlin which works fine:

```
var
  aRowColor: TBrush;
begin
  //it's better to write this line into create
  aRowColor := Tbrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid,TAlphaColors.Alpha);
  //-----
  grid.DefaultDrawing := False;
  if (myTbl.RcrdDataCount > 0) and (Row < myTbl.RcrdDataCount) then begin
    if myTbl.RcrdDataItems[Row].State = TStateDeleted then begin
      aRowColor.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;
    end
    else begin
      aRowColor.Color := TAlphaColors.Gray;
    end;
    Canvas.FillRect(Bounds, 0, 0, [], 1, aRowColor);
    Column.DefaultDrawCell(Canvas, Bounds, Row, Value, State);
  end;
  //it's better to write this line into destroy
  aRowColor.free;
  //-----
end;
```